# Custom Shape in flutter Like OvalShape

Tags: flutter, shapes, custom-ui, flutter-ui, customclipper

I'm working on a Flutter project and I need to create a custom shape that looks like the one shown below:

[image]
[image]

I've attempted to use CustomShapeClipper, but I couldn't quite achieve the exact shape I need.

I've heard about the CustomPainter widget in Flutter, but I'm not familiar with it. Can someone provide guidance on how to create this specific shape using CustomPainter or suggest alternative approaches to achieve it?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can search for Custom path widget and draw your desired shape

Comment: if you have svg of that images you can create the easily.

Comment: I have an SVG file, but I'm not sure how it can help me. Can you provide some guidance? @MunsifAli

Comment: you can use svg directly and also you can create custom shape from the svg with code. check the answer for code generation.

Answer (score 1):

using [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/#/) you can create CustomPainter code from any svg.

go to the website on the top left there is a button named `Svg to customPaint` paste your svg code there or browse your svg file and it will generate the code for you use it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to achieve oval shape you can use `ShapeDecoration` in container and set the `shape` to `StadiumBorder` like below:

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              shape: StadiumBorder(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```